# Who are the robots in the captcha request?

Tags: discussion, captcha, robots

When you are too fast in interacting with SO, a captcha request appears, together with a photo of two gentlemen dressed as robots.

Who are they ?

Comment: I bet it was a random picture from Google Images.

Comment: I just searched like the first 20 pages of "two robots" :) Nothing.

Comment: I think Jermaine is the Pusher and Bret is the Shover.

Comment: That's some very dirty talk

Comment: you know you can **CLICK THE IMAGE** to have all be revealed, right? Not like it's some massively hidden secret.

Comment: @Jeff: When I am asked for a captcha, my robotic nature forces me to obey the order of solving it. I don't investigate further.

Comment: Yeah, who's the robot now?!

Comment: @Jeff: let's not go philosophical now ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's Jemaine and Bret from **[Flight of the Conchords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Conchords_(TV_series))**.  Specifically, the episode called [*Sally*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_(Flight_of_the_Conchords)#.22Robots.22).  [Here's the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvrva8NoMLM).

Comment: Do they know they're famous now?

Comment: More importantly, how will Murray screw this over?

Comment: @John, wouldn't that involve them *not* being famous to begin with? I mean they have a TV show...

Comment: +1 for providing the video?!? **THE VIDEO IS LINKED ON THE IMAGE ON THE SITE!!** (head asplode)

Comment: @Jeff: I hope you've learned a little something about UI usability from this: people clearly don't know that images are links unless they have a blue border.

Comment: Feature request: Make it obvious that robot picture is an HTML link.

Answer (score 8):

They remind me of the [Flight of the Conchords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Conchords)...Jemaine and Bret.

Comment: Because they *are* Jermaine and Bret

Comment: I guess that if life was a D&D campaign, this would be a 20 in bardic lore.

Comment: @Ian: Actually, they're *Jemaine* and Bret.  No 'r'.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just sorry it's not Jeff and Joel.

Answer (score 2):

I think they might be Daft Punk

Comment: I think *you* might be daft, punk.