# Add a link on the 404 page users can follow to get the joke

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, 404-not-found

I just saw this question:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code

And it occurs to me this is likely to be the first of many; the polyglot joke is a little obscure.  Could we add a link to the page that either points to the meta question where you ask for suggestions or the question I just linked to, in an effort to avoid users repeating the question every few days?

Comment: How about giant arrows and freehand circles to explain?

Comment: Um.... no. Not really a fan.  I'm ready for that to blow over already.

Comment: Hey I started something, *unfortunately it's because of my stupidness.*

Answer (score 8):

You have high hopes for [people clicking on the image for an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11319/who-are-the-robots-in-the-captcha-request).

They'll need something like a big bright link text to clue them in about the 404 page contest.

[image: for the link deprived]

Comment: *Holly hand\-drawn\-decorated\-with\-paint\-code Batman!*

Comment: Well, I'm a fan of any kind of freehand painting :)