# Two guys in robot suits

Tags: discussion, captcha, robots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who are the robots in the captcha request?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11319/who-are-the-robots-in-the-captcha-request)

On the CAPTCHA request, who are the two guys in "robot" suits?

Answer (score 2):

They are the top New Zealand singing duo, Flight Of The Concords.  The picture is a still from [the video for their song "The humans are dead"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvrva8NoMLM)  (The song is also called "Robots"in some places.  Those krazy Kiwis!)

Comment: Actually, the title of the song is simply *Robots*.

Comment: @raven - According to that unimpeachable source of truth, Wikipedia, the song goes by either name: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_(Flight_of_the_Conchords)

Comment: I have the CD.  The title of the song is "Robots".  I think that trumps wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is fair use, or a copyright violation?